# ntox86-ld: cannot find -lminiupnpc

Tags: blackberry-10

I am trying to build a pjsip based project for blackberry 10,
but I get errors when compiling:

```
../src/navigator.cpp:63:6: warning: unused parameter 'type' [-Wunused-parameter]
/opt/bbndk/host_10_1_0_132/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-ld: skipping incompatible /root/blackberry/fiume/lib/upnp/libminiupnpc.a when searching for -lminiupnpc
qcc -Vgcc_ntox86 -lang-c++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1020/qnx6/x86/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1020/qnx6/x86/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1020/qnx6/x86/usr/lib/qt4/lib -o o-g/fiume o-g/.obj/AddressBook.o o-g/.obj/AudioManager.o o-g/.obj/BpsPlatform.o o-g/.obj/ContactEditor.o o-g/.obj/ContactViewer.o o-g/.obj/Fiume.o o-g/.obj/PjCallback.o o-g/.obj/buddy.o o-g/.obj/callhistory.o o-g/.obj/callhistoryrecord.o o-g/.obj/debugger.o o-g/.obj/kuzaranda.o o-g/.obj/main.o o-g/.obj/navigator.o o-g/.obj/moc_AddressBook.o o-g/.obj/moc_AudioManager.o o-g/.obj/moc_BpsPlatform.o o-g/.obj/moc_ContactEditor.o o-g/.obj/moc_ContactViewer.o o-g/.obj/moc_Fiume.o o-g/.obj/moc_PjCallback.o o-g/.obj/moc_buddy.o o-g/.obj/moc_callhistory.o o-g/.obj/moc_callhistoryrecord.o o-g/.obj/moc_debugger.o o-g/.obj/moc_kuzaranda.o o-g/.obj/moc_navigator.o    -L/opt/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1020/qnx6/x86/lib -L/opt/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1020/qnx6/x86/usr/lib -L/opt/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1020/qnx6/x86/usr/lib/qt4/lib -L/opt/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1020/qnx6//usr/lib/qt4/lib -L/root/blackberry/fiume/lib -L/root/blackberry/fiume/lib/upnp -lpjsua-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjsip-ua-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjsip-simple-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjsip-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjmedia-codec-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjmedia-videodev-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjmedia-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjmedia-audiodev-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lspeex-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lopencore-amrnb -lgsmcodec-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lilbccodec-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lg7221codec-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjnath-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjlib-util-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lresample-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lmilenage-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lsrtp-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lportaudio-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpj-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lpjsdp-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0 -lasound -lcrypto -lssl -lminiupnpc -lbbpim -laudio_manager -lbb -lbbsystem -lbbplatform -lscreen -L/opt/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1020/qnx6/usr/share/qt4/lib -lQtSensors -lbbcascades -lQtDeclarative -lQtScript -lQtSvg -lQtSql -lsqlite3 -lz -lQtXmlPatterns -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lsocket -lQtCore -lm -lbps 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/blackberry/fiume/x86'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/blackberry/fiume/x86'
/opt/bbndk/host_10_1_0_132/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-ld: cannot find -lminiupnpc
cc: /opt/bbndk/host_10_1_0_132/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-ld error 1
make[2]: *** [o-g/fiume] Error 1
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make: *** [Simulator-Debug] Error 2``

**** Build Finished ****`
```

Why is `libminiupnpc.a` considered "incompatible", and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that `libminiupnpc.a` was compiled for the ARM architecture, rather than the one you want (x86). Try recompiling it using `qcc -Vgcc_ntox86`